# Getting a with_dict error when reading through dict:

Tags: yaml, ansible

This may not be an issue on the module but certainly for me and I hope I can get an answer from here.
I am trying to run a play book with variables defined in group_vars folder. however when I run the playbook Ansible throws an error saying "fatal: [spine111] => with_dict expects a dict".
What am I doing wrong?

My /roles/tasks/main.yml is:

```
- name: peerlink.4094 configuration for peer1 only
 cl_interface:
   name: "{{ item.key }}"
   ipv4: "{{ item.value.ipv4 }}"
   alias_name: "{{ item.value.alias_name }}"
   clagd_enable: "{{ item.value.clagd_enable }}"
   clagd_peer_ip: "{{ item.value.clagd_peer_ip }}"
   clagd_priority: "{{ item.value.clagd_priority }}"
   clagd_sys_mac: "{{ item.value.clagd_sys_mac }}"
   clagd_args: "{{ item.value.clagd_args }}"
   applyconfig: 'yes'
 with_dict: cl_interfaces[inventory_hostname]
 notify: reload networking
 tags: clagd
```

And my group_vars/peer output is:

```
cl_interface:
  spine111:
    peerlink.4094:
      alias_name: "Clag_PeerLink"
      ipv4: "169.254.1.1/30"
      clagd_enable: "yes"
      clagd_peer_ip: "169.254.1.2"
      clagd_priority: "4096"
      clagd_args: "-vm"
      clagd_sys_mac: "00:00:00:00:00:01"
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer with the help of Jason https://community.cumulusnetworks.com/cumulus/topics/getting-a-with-dict-error-when-reading-through-dict

There was an additional "s" when the discretionary was being called. :(

And by the way there was one more error in my variable file that was related to indenting... I had 2 spaces instead of 4 :(